# Divide the whole money into fraction depending on price and show balance jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
var paidamount = 500;
var amountpaid = 0;
var balance_amount = 0;
var list = [];
$("table tr").each(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  var price = $this.find('td:nth-child(1)').text();

  if (paidamount >= parseFloat(price)) {
    paidamount -= parseFloat(price);
    amountpaid = price;
    balance_amount = 0;
  } else {
    amountpaid = 0;
    balance_amount = price;
  }

  list.push({
    price: price,
    paid_amount: amountpaid,
    balance: balance_amount
  });

});


for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
  $("table tbody").empty();
  var tr = $('<tr/>');
  tr.append("<td width=20>" + list[i].price + "</td>");
  tr.append("<td width=140 >" + list[i].paid_amount + "</td>");
  tr.append("<td width=140 >" + list[i].balance + "</td>");
  $("table tbody").append(tr);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td width="40" class="">300.00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="40" class="">190.00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="40" class="">150.00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="40" class="">150.00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="40" class="">150.00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="40" class="">150.00</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

At start I have 500 as starting price then I want to distribute it on each tr until it is down to zero.

Expected:

First row first column is price 300 then second column is should be 300 since 500 is enough to pay 300 then balance is 0 since 300 is full paid. next row is 190 for price then second should be 190 since 200 is enough to pay 190 then balance is zero since 190 is full paid. next row 150 second row is 10 since 10 is what is left from previous transaction then last column is 140 since 150 is not paid completely and only 10 is paid. Rest will have balance of price then not paid amount since the cash left is 0 .

Comment: May it help! [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kn27phwm/#&togetherjs=DhOdJrxTDC)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've updated your code to fix the issues. One of the fixes is to remove the `$("table tbody").empty();` statement out of the for loop, you only need to run this once. If you keep it inside the for loop, it'll empty the table after each iteration and only the last row will be appended.

Secondly I simplified the logic inside the `$("table tr").each()` function. You should move all variables that are local to a particular row to be inside this function, logically it makes more sense, so you don't have to reset it after each iteration. The logic is simple, you set a `tempAmount` equal to the `startingAmount`(500) minus the price of the row. Then set `amountPaid` equal to `price` and `balanceAmount` equal to `0`. Assume they have been fully paid. Then check to see that the `tempAmount` is still greater than `0`, if so its correctly fully paid, otherwise you don't have enough to pay. In this case, just update the `amountPaid`to equal the the remaining amount , which at this point is `startingAmount`, and update `balanceAmount` to equal `price` minus `startingAmount`. Finally set the `startingAmount` to `0` so all future iterations will result in the `else` statement running.

```js
var startingAmount = 500;
var list = [];
$("table tr").each(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  var price = parseFloat($this.find('td:nth-child(1)').text());
  var tempAmount = startingAmount - price;
  var amountPaid = price;
  var balanceAmount = 0;
  if(tempAmount > 0){
     startingAmount = tempAmount;
  }else{
     amountPaid = startingAmount;
     balanceAmount = price - startingAmount;
     startingAmount = 0;
  }

  list.push({
    price: price,
    paid_amount: amountPaid,
    balance: balanceAmount
  });

});

$("table tbody").empty();
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
  var tr = $('<tr/>');
  tr.append("<td width=20>" + list[i].price + "</td>");
  tr.append("<td width=140 >" + list[i].paid_amount + "</td>");
  tr.append("<td width=140 >" + list[i].balance + "</td>");
  $("table tbody").append(tr);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td width="40" class="">300.00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="40" class="">190.00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="40" class="">150.00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="40" class="">150.00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="40" class="">150.00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="40" class="">150.00</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: this is very clear let me try it on my code give me a minute